# Drop down Menu Width

Tags: css, menu

I have a demo here [www.ttmt.org.uk/nav](http://www.ttmt.org.uk/nav)

It's a simple list navigation with drop downs

The 'Our Work' drop down has another drop down on the last button.

The drop downs are wider than the parent buttons but the drop under the last button of 'Our Work' isn't wide enough for the text.

Why are these button not wide enough.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">  

      <!--css-->
      <style>

        body{
            background:#eee;
            font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        nav{
            margin:50px;
            float:left;
        }

        nav ul ul{
            display:none;
        }
        nav ul li:hover > ul{
            display:block;
        }
        nav ul{
            list-style:none;
            position:relative;
            display:inline-table;
        }
        nav ul:after {
            content: "";
            clear: both; 
            display: block;
        }

        nav ul li{
            float:left;
        }
        nav ul li a{
            display:block;
            padding:20px;
            text-decoration:none;
            background:#fff;
            color:red;
            margin:0 5px 0 0;
            position:relative;
        }
        nav ul li a span{
            display:inline-block;
            width:14px;
            height:7px;
            background:blue;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:10px;
            left:50%;
            margin-left:-7px;
        }
        nav ul ul{
            padding:0;
            position:absolute;
            top:100%;
        }
        nav ul ul li{
            float:none;
            position:relative;
        }
        nav ul ul li a{
            background:red;
            color:#fff;
            margin:0 0 5px 0;
        }
        nav ul ul ul{
            position:absolute;
            left:100%;
            top:0;
        }

      </style>


      <title>Title of the document</title>
      </head>

    <body>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home<span></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us ><span></span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">About Us Bigger Button</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us Us Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us Us Us Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Work ><span></span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Our Work One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Our Work Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Our Work Three ></a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Our Work Three Sub Button</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Our Work Three Another Sub Button</a></li>
                </ul>  
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact<span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your css

```
nav ul ul ul {
      width: 200px; /* example width */
}
```

Comment: I know I can do that but it's not very dynamic. I haven't given the other ul a width.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `width: 100%;` to this selector `nav ul ul ul`. Thus - the `ul`s will at least have the same width.

P.s. try adding some classes to your html, so that you didn't have such long and slow selectors as `nav ul ul ul` and could address directly like `.submenu`

Comment: I'll look into adding classes but it's a Wordpress menu and I'm not sure how I would add them

Comment: Wordpress allows to add classes both to the menu container and to the menu itself :) http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu